# Retrieve data from Firebase using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script

I'm developing a Google Spreadsheet to manage reservations for a hotel. It has two main tabs. One of them is used to make the reservations and the other one is used to make queries to the reservations already made. I managed to make it work just fine with the built-in tools of google apps script using a tab as database.

I'm trying to export my data to a Firebase database, but I cannot find how to fetch some information I need. My data is stored using a code generated using the date of the reservation as integer format + the name of the person without spaces. This is the JSON generated by firebase:

```
{
  "44256001LarissaMeimbergBaraldi" : {
    "code" : 44256001,
    "date" : "2021-03-01T03:00:00.000Z",
    "name" : "Larissa Meimberg Baraldi"
  },
  "44256001ÍcaroNovodeOliveira" : {
    "code" : 44256001,
    "date" : "2021-03-01T03:00:00.000Z",
    "name" : "Ícaro Novo de Oliveira"
  }
}
```

My question is: let's suppose I want to know all the reservations made for the day 01/March/2021, what is the code for me to look inside the objects and then, if they match my search, get the info I need?

Comment: I think if you get an array of objects from firebase you would have a much easier time analyzing and querying the data, like this [{},{}], instead of having a different object property  for every name.

Comment: You mean by setting one array to retrieve all the content of the database and then 
analyzing its whole length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help! But my point was actually a little bit different, maybe I wasn't so clear.

While trying to explain it to you, I found the answer to my question. It was right under my nose this whole time and I didn't notice it. Here is the solution I needed:

First, I have to assign a rule to my firebase telling it what element I will be working on, so if I want to find reservations based on the date, it would look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".indexOn":["date"]
  }
}
```

Then, back to my script, it will be like:

```
function getReservations() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Search');
  var date = ss.getRange('C11').getValue();
  var firebaseUrl = "https://script-examples.firebaseio.com/";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var queryParameters = {orderBy:"date", equalTo: date};
  var data = base.getData("", queryParameters);
  for(var i in data) {
    Logger.log(data[i].code, data[i].name, data[i].date);
  }
}
```

The log retrieves:

```
[20-12-08 11:30:33:696 BRT] 44256001 Larissa Meimberg Baraldi 2021-03-01T03:00:00.000Z
[20-12-08 11:30:33:698 BRT] 44256001 Ícaro Novo de Oliveira 2021-03-01T03:00:00.000Z
```

This information was described on the documentation here:

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script

I think I got a little overwhelmed with the amount of information I got and skipped this part of the tutorial.

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the JSON to an array of objects, then filtered by date. Added the console logs to check if everything is right. You can see the logs when you go to view -> executions in your script. Click on the function execution to see the logged objects.

```
function myFunction() {
  var a ={
  "44256001LarissaMeimbergBaraldi" : {
    "code" : 44256001,
    "date" : "2021-03-01T03:00:00.000Z",
    "name" : "Larissa Meimberg Baraldi"
  },
  "44256001ÍcaroNovodeOliveira" : {
    "code" : 44256001,
    "date" : "2021-03-01T03:00:00.000Z",
    "name" : "Ícaro Novo de Oliveira"
  },
  "44256002ÍcaroNovodeOliveira" : {
    "code" : 44256002,
    "date" : "2021-04-01T03:00:00.000Z",
    "name" : "Ícaro Dovo de Oliveira"
  }
};
  var values_a = Object.values(a);
  var keys_a = Object.keys(a);
  var array_a = keys_a.map((item, index)=> {return {"key": item, "values": values_a[index]};});
  console.log(array_a);
  var filter_date = "2021-03-01T03:00:00.000Z";
  var filtered_a=array_a.filter(item => {return item.values.date === filter_date;})
  console.log(filtered_a);
  
}
```